# What's a good free open source hard drive benchmark?

Tags: hard-drive, benchmark, hdparm

After a quick search on Freshmeat I found nothing. Anybody know of a good utility?

I normally use time (dd if=/dev/zero of=newfile ...)  to test write speed
and hdparm -t to test read speed.

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a utility written in java: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdiskmark/

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at bonnie and bonnie++, they will give you pretty much information.

http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/

Comment: I tried compiling the bonnie that I found on Freshmeat but it was DOA. I'll try the one you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @Stewie: On what OS are you? On most distributions Bonnie and/or Bonnie++ are available to install from the standard repositories.

Comment: forget about bonnie and use bonnie++. It's included in nearly every linux distro and also available for other OSes (eg. MacPorts for darwin/osx)

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at [IOZone](http://www.iozone.org/).  Its a command line tool that runs under many operating systems and should be available to install with your standard package tools.

From their website:

> The benchmark tests file I/O performance for the following operations:
>   Read, write, re-read, re-write, read backwards, read strided, fread, fwrite, random read, pread ,mmap, aio_read, aio_write

Answer (score 0):

`dd` and `bonnie++` are good instruments if you need, simple, specific, synthetic measurements. They're good, for example, to establish a baseline performance of a "naked" disk (mb/sec and latency) before adding layers over it (raid, lvm, drbd, iSCSI, etc...) and then check if you lost some performance somewhere. I wouldn't use hdparm for that.

[IOZone](http://www.iozone.org), [Iometer](http://www.iometer.org) are better at simulating actual workloads. There are also some more specific tools, like [Postal](http://doc.coker.com.au/projects/postal/) to simulate email workloads and a number of SQL-related tools to benchmark databases (these are usually db-specific benchmark tools and will measure the whole performance of the system, that includes a number of factors other than disks alone)